# Singleton pattern used by three classes

Tags: c#

Interviewer asked me this question:

> You have implemented the singleton Pattern and it is used by 3
>   classes, one class disposed the object. Does other two classes still
>   able to access?

how does that work?
could you please explain?

Comment: By disposed, do you mean "set it to null", or calling some theoretical `dispose()` method (that should not exist on a singleton ever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Singleton Pattern and it is used by 3 classes

I am assuming they meant 3 variables/references, not classes.

**Example**:

```
var a = MyClass.Instance;
var b = MyClass.Instance;
var c = MyClass.Instance;
```

> one class disposed the object - does other two classes still able to
>   access?

No

> how it will work? could you please explain?

The purpose of the singelton pattern is to only have one instance of the class. So, whenever it is referenced i.e., (a, b, c) above, it is the same instance (it's pointing to the same address in memory).

So, if one of the classes disposed of the instance, this will mean that all references that currently point to the singleton will also have the disposed object as well (since all references were pointing to the same address location where the object lived).

**Example:**

```
a.Dispose(); // will dispose MyClass.Instance, making all references to it also have the disposed object

// a will now be disposed
// b will now be disposed 
// c will now be disposed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear explanation.

Comment: Singleton should create its instance if the instance is not initialized though, which is usually done with a null check. So if "dispose" means the instance was destroyed and set to null, then, depending on the implementation, a new call to get the instance might just recreate it. It also depends on whether these other classes keep a local reference or request the singleton each time.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a Singleton, then that means there is only one instance of it - everyone who references it gets the same instance.  If you were to dispose the instance - though that seems pretty odd as a concept for a Singleton - then the classes that then try to reference it would likely get an [ObjectDisposedException](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=objectdisposedexception)

Comment: Agreed, the oddity of a design such as this is sounds very impractical.